# Extract data from text file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to extract data from a .txt file and place it into a database. The data are the numbers next to the colon. I've tried the File.ReadAllLines function but some lines have the same word. Below is part of the text file:

X centroid offset: 0.1233 mm

Y centroid offset: -0.00053871 mm

Eccentricity (Beam): 0.10004

Eccentricity (Shadow): 0.118

Here is the start of my code. I'm trying to place those values into the database as variables which I have defined.

```
private void btn_import_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        string Date;
        float A_X_Off;
        float A_Y_Off;
        float A_EccBeam;
        float A_EccSha;

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;
        Data Source = C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Desktop\\Accuray Project\\CkAppDatabase.accdb";


        // CODE to pull out text file values and make the output a variable.                    

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into CK_QA_App(Date, A_X_Off, A_Y_Off, A_EccBeam, A_EccSha) VALUES(@Date, @A_X_Off, @A_Y_Off, @A_EccBeam, @EccSha)");

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {                         

        }
```

Comment: So you don't have code to read the data from the text file and you don't have the complete code to insert records into your database? Sounds like two questions.

Comment: My apologies crashmstr. Reading the data from the text file is my only question.

Comment: Can you expand on 'some lines have the same word' I'm not sure what you mean here? Do you mean the result of that method is incorrect because some lines are duplicated? That seems highly unlikely as that's a core framework function

Comment: read up on the `Split()` Method along with `File.ReadAllText` Method..

Comment: You only want to extract the numbers in each line? If yes, how can you identify those numbers? Are they always placed after the colon ":" ?

Comment: @ChadiAbouSleiman what are you taking about if he has a text file and there is a common delimiter such as `spaces, Tabs, ;`  `,` etc.. this would require using the Split() method to quickly store those values in a string[]

Comment: If the data is being read incorrectly, could you update the question with the code you're using to read the text file?

Comment: Note that \s are not metacharacters in verbatim `@` strings; you want either `@"... Data Source = C:\Users\Kevin\..."` or `"... Data Source = C:\\Users\\Kevin\\..."`, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using File.ReadAllLines you can use a for loop over the result.

Inside the loop use the starts with method and some ifs to match the line to the correct variable to assign it to.

Use the split function using the colon to split to get the value out. Remember to call trim on the value to remove the leading space.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use the split function in this format: string A_X_Off = line[9].Split(' ')[3], to get the exact line and column after the split. For some reason the trim function wasn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're reading from the text File `f`:

```
string[] inputs = File.ReadAllLines(f);

foreach (String line in inputs) {

string data = Regex.Match(line, @"-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?").Value;
//This will extract any decimal in each line as a string
//you can then parse it to double/float or any type you want and store it in your database

}
```